# React js index.html file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I created my react app from scratch. There are some js when I include in index.html file it gives 404 error
Also I used this scripts in create-react-app boilerplate its working
there is issue in webpack config I think.
Here is my webpack config:

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const Dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");
const webPack = require("webpack");
const PUBLIC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "public/assets");
const webpackPlugins = [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/index.html"),
    filename: "index.html",
    inject: true,
  }),
  new Dotenv({
    path: "./.env", // Path to .env file (this is the default)
    systemvars: true,
  }),
  new webPack.DefinePlugin({
    "process.env.PUBLIC_DIR": JSON.stringify(PUBLIC_DIR),
  }),
];
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "main.js",
    publicPath: "/",
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    static: false,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: { presets: ["@babel/env"] },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "url-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"] },
  plugins: webpackPlugins,
};
```

index file
index file added please see this if I'm missing anything
its working in create-react-app boiler plate but not here
any suggestion or should I switch to create-react-app boilerplate

```html
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/app.plugin.js"></script>
</body>
```

also this is my folder structure
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RL8b.png)

Comment: Please show `index.html` file and your top level folder structure including the js files you want to directly include in `index.html`.

Comment: I voted to close this question because the code sample is too long. Please [edit] your post to pare your code down to a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Teejaay keep your index.html file inside src directory then try again to start your server

Comment: @Teejaay this is my react app structure which I have created from scratch see in the image link -  https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/kings-landing-b1726.appspot.com/o/Screenshot%20(209)_LI.jpg?alt=media&token=e772239b-f06e-4a7e-89f7-1a51cb7ca17c